# Show/Hide element when clicking buttons

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons Show and Hide and I have an image so I want to know when I click the hide button the img will disappear and when I click show button it will appear again. And I don't want to do it with CSS or JQUERY only Javascript. If someone can help thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var myImg = document.getElementById('myImg');
  
  document.getElementById('hideBtn').onclick = function(){
      myImg.style.display = 'none';
  };
  
  document.getElementById('showBtn').onclick = function(){
      myImg.style.display = '';
  };
  
  document.getElementById('toggleBtn').onclick = function(){
      var display = getComputedStyle(myImg).display=='none'?'':'none';
      myImg.style.display = display;
  };
}
```

```html
<button id="hideBtn">Hide</button>
<button id="showBtn">Show</button>
<button id="toggleBtn">Toggle</button>
<br/>
<img id="myImg" src="http://www.eastcottvets.co.uk/uploads/Animals/gingerkitten.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just what I was looking for even though I didn't need togglebtn to write down but more information is better because I'm new to javascript so more information is better for me and one more time thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry to bother you but what if we have 5 lists and in those 5 list we have 2 buttons Show/Hide and 1 img. How can we do it for all the lists that the img can show and hide ?

Comment: @EndritShala Since IDs must be unique, you might want to use classes instead, and do this: http://jsfiddle.net/shjg4vf9/

Answer (score 1):

```js
function show(){
  document.getElementById('image').style.display = "inline";
  }

function hide(){
  document.getElementById('image').style.display = "none";
  }
```

```html
<img src="http://colorvisiontesting.com/images/plate%20with%205.jpg" width="80px" height="80px" id="image"/><br />
<button onClick="hide();">Hide</button>
<button onClick="show();">Show</button>
```